# some media queries in my css are ignored

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have the following css. The first '4 columns' media queries work, the rest is ignored. If I put '5-columns' before '1-column' that one works but '1, 6 and 7 are ignored. If I put 6 above that one works, but 1 and 5 are ignored. 2, 3 and 4 columns keep working no matter where I put them. I don't see the problem. I hope anyone can help me out.

```
#header-wrap {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
    margin: 32px 32px 16px;
    padding: 0 0 32px;
}

/* 1 column */
@media all and (max-width: 607px) {
    #header-wrap {
    width: 256px;
    }
}

/* 2 columns */
@media all and (min-width:607px) and (max-width:895px) {
    #header-wrap {
    width: 544px;
    }
}

/* 3 columns */
@media all and (min-width:895px) and (max-width:1183px) {
    #header-wrap {
    width: 832px;
    }
}

/* 4 columns */
@media all and (min-width:1183px) and (max-width:1471px) {
    #header-wrap {
    width: 1120px;
    }
}​

/* 5 columns */
@media all and (min-width:1471px) and (max-width:1759px) {
    #header-wrap {
    width: 1408px;
    }
}​

/* 6 columns */
@media all and (min-width:1759px) and (max-width:2062px) {
    #header-wrap {
    width: 1696px;
    }
}​

/* 7 columns */
@media all and (min-width:2062px) {
    #header-wrap {
    width: 1696px;
    }
}​
```

Comment: Con you please post your HTML code?

Comment: I've replicated your code, and in fact it won't activate the css from the fifth media query, using clases instead of id's didn't work, i tried several things but none work, i'll be interesting if somebody knows of this behavior.

Comment: This is the html:

<div id="header-wrap">
some content here
</div> <!-- header-wrap  -->

Answer (score 0):

Got it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5V5xf/)

For some reason, there were dots following some of your closing square brackets. Not sure where they came from.

I also trimmed down your media queries for the same effect with less code. Loosely speaking, there are 3 main methods of targeting a screen. You can let your styles:

1. style down e.g. `(min-width:320px)`, so everything *down* to that size
2. style up `(max-width:480px)`, everything *up* to that size
3. bracket `(min-width:320px) and (max-width:480px)`

What you had there is bracketing, where rather than allowing the styles within the media queries to cascade i.e. a 1200px wide screen meets `(min-width:600px)` and `(min-width:1000px)` so you only need apply a style to the lower value query, you have to re-apply styles based on a specific bracketed resolution, such as `(min-width:600px) and (max-width:800px)`.

This is a totally legit technique, but you'll find you end up with a lot more code to maintain if any changes are ever needed. I learnt this one the hard way. CSS is designed to cascade, and media queries are the same.

Lastly, if you are going to use the bracket approach, try to avoid specifying the same resolution twice

i.e. `(min-width:320px) and (max-width:500px)` then `(min-width:500px) and (max-width:900px)`

as this may confuse some browsers or cause flickering when resizing a screen, because there is a single pixel that meets both conditions. The safe way to write it would be:

```
 `(min-width:320px) and (max-width:500px)`
```

then `(min-width:501px) and (max-width:900px)`

Failing that, styling up or down eliminates this possibility altogether :)

Comment: Wow thanks for your answer and the explanation!

Where you see dots I saw spaces (so I did not see them).